# Soundcloud: sharing tracks to groups via PHP?

Tags: php, share, soundcloud

I've written a bunch of different and working soundcloud PHP scripts based on the following API wrapper: http://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

However I still can't share tracks to groups via PHP. I've tried everything, spent hours and hours and tried all different syntax variations and read every question on this topic (I'm not the only one with this problem) on Stackoverflow and other sites but to no avail.

So can someone give me a working piece of code (based on aforementioned wrapper) that **does** work or at least confirm that SC changed something in their code maybe which makes it impossible to do this?

As for examples what I did: it's been a while and I didn't keep all my trials. Here are two of the variations (the first one is the last I tried):

```
$track = array('track[id]' => '205761293');
try {
    $response = json_decode(
        $client->post('http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/175027/contributions.json?client_id=$clientID', $track,
            array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml'))
        ),
        true
    );
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

$clientID is a variable that I created earlier on in my ini code which **is** right; I use it all the time. The groupID above is hard coded to keep things simple.

**I also tried the standard SC method which reads something like this:**

```
$group = $client->post('http://api.soundcloud.com/groups/204898/contributions/207287906.json?client_id=$clientID', array('true'));
```

where the last number is the hard coded trackID. I also tried "put" instead of "post" and different other things I found on the web but this is what I can remember now.

Comment: What _are_ the code variations you tried?

Comment: Thanks dakab. I was a bit afraid of that question: it's been a while and I can't remember everything I did (and I'm not "into it" anymore). See the edits above I made to my question. Hopefully it'll help somewhat.